# Update to iphone app not pushed to me

Tags: iphone, app-store, itunes-store

I provided a new binary for a new version of my first iphone app. The new version is ready for sale today. However, when I check the app store notifications, no notification has come to me to update this app. The store version reflects the new version. Did I have to do something specific to let apple know that this needs to be pushed to the current users as an update??:(

Comment: This is not a programming question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your new version is listed as being ready for sale, (which it is) then you're done. Apple do the notifications to users that have installed your app and when they have web access - they'll see a +1 badge on their app store icon.

Comment: yup guess I panicked too soon. The app on my phone was my testing version from the development profile, checked with other users, and they have the update indication from apple. Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 1):

It will take some time for app to propagate trough app store.. usually an hour or a two after it reaches "ready for sale state" so the best thing is to wait a little bit...